# ASP.NET <location path= and authentication mode

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

Can anyone please tell me whether the `<location path=` works when we set `<authentication mode= "None" />` ?

Comment: what do you mean by "works" - how do you expect the application to behave?

Comment: Yes. "works" mean whether the <location path=.. /> has any effect when we set the authentication mode to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does.

Check this post:
[Authentification-None for one folder(page) when the project is under FormsAuthentifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364618/authentification-none-for-one-folderpage-when-the-project-is-under-formsauthent) which shares an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<location path="Recovery">      //Path of the folder or form You want to allow
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If u dont want to allow  unauthorized user type "?"

Comment: Thanks but my question is whether your code, authorize the users when we set the <authentication mode= "None" /> ???

Comment: if you don't want to authorize the user then just type "*" that will allow all user to access the form or folder.